# How to send RESTful request to the back-end implemented in Java from fron-end implemented in NW.js?

Tags: java, tomcat, nw.js

I have a web application whose front-end is implemented in extjs and back-end is implemented in java. The web application can run successfully when deployed both front-end and back-end in Tomcat.

Now, I want to change it into standalone desktop app.
What I did is as below:

1. Save as all the front-end resource to local host and wrapped them in NW.js
2. Deploy back-end part still in tomcat which is local

Now the issue I got is:

When front-end called in NW.js send RESTful request to back-end, the url is changed into "chrome-extension://pedkhegghbakdeaeelkjnajoobkpibbd/sso/auth". The correct one should be "http://localhost:8080/sso/auth"

Am I using NW.js in a wrong way?

The version I am using is nwjs-sdk-v0.22.3-win-ia32. The OS version is Windows 7 32 bit.

The index.html is attached.

The package.json is:

```
{
"name": "demo",
"main": "index.html"
}
```

The html contains `<form action="auth" method="post">` to send request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is targeting a relative URL. You need to target your fully qualified `/sso/auth` endpoint.

Assuming you aren't manipulating the post with JS, changing your html to

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/sso/auth" method="post">
```

Should resolve your issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, this indeed can send url successfully. But there are too many relative URLs in my application. I don't want to change all of them manually. Is there any way that NW.js can     complement all of them with "http://ip:8080" configured automatically?

Comment: The you can use gui.App.setProxyConfig or the Chromium proxy configurations. I'll update my answer with an example if you need it.

Comment: Yes, i need it. that will be very helpful. Thank you very much.